# Set multiple tables primary keys in one query?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

So i'd like to set the primary keys for multiple tables in postgressql, is this even possible as a single query? and if it is possible then i'm running into a error  "syntax error at or near "TABLE""

The query i am sending is, with the above error message,

```
set_primary_keys = """ALTER TABLE public.dim_store_details ADD PRIMARY KEY (store_code),
                      ALTER TABLE public.dim_products ADD PRIMARY KEY (product_code),
                      ALTER TABLE public.dim_users ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_uuid);

"""
```

So i figured maybe it is a syntax error so i ended up doing where i thought the semicolon is used for separating tables

```
set_primary_keys = """ALTER TABLE public.dim_store_details ADD PRIMARY KEY (store_code);
                      ALTER TABLE public.dim_products ADD PRIMARY KEY (product_code);
                      ALTER TABLE public.dim_users ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_uuid);
```

"""

Which caused this error, multiple primary keys for table "dim_store_details" are not allowed

Not really sure how to get past this

Comment: You’re probably getting that error because you’ve already set a primary key, try removing the current one first.

Comment: Yeah i already set the primary key for the first table, because i wanted to see if the query just goes through, then i tried adding for the rest of the tables and that's when the error came, so i tried removing the first line but it came up with the same error for dim_products so i'm guessing there's a specific way to do it or you can only alter one table at a time

Comment: Why would you do that? Just run three separated queries. You are testing non-standard quirks that most likely won't work in other databases.

Comment: @TheImpaler I did try to search what I wanted to do and couldn't find anything. So I think you're right tbh, even in postgressql you cannot rename multiple columns at once so must be the same issue with accesing multiple tables at once

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do the second version, but there's clearly already a primary key.

The following will show you all primary keys.

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Use the constraint_name column to drop the primary keys blocking your query. Then run the query again.